# best way customize field_error in symfony 3

Tags: symfony, twig

i have a entity with  path field

```
  /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload scontrino/fattura della stufa acquistata.")
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/pdf","image/png" ,"image/jpg","image/jpeg" })
     * @ORM\Column(name="path_file", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;
```

i have this field in a form

```
->add('path', FileType::class, array('data_class' => null))
;
```

and in the twig file

```
<div class="row">
                                                    <div class="input-field col s12 ">
                                                         {{ form_errors(form.path) }}
                                                        {{ form_widget(form.path) }}

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

when i press submit button and i put i not allowed file now my message is

```
Il mime type del file non è valido ("application/zip"). I tipi permessi sono "application/pdf", "image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg".
```

I want to change that message but i don't understand the best way to do that.
If i must do it in entity file or in form file or in twig file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add: 
    `mimeTypesMessage = "with the text you want"`, in the `@Assert\File
in your @Assert\File` of your entity

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload scontrino/fattura della stufa acquistata.")
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/pdf","image/png" ,"image/jpg","image/jpeg" }, mimeTypesMessage = "with the text you want")
 * @ORM\Column(name="path_file", type="string", length=255)
 */
```

[The symfony Reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#uploaderrormessage)

Comment: great . it work and if i want i red message ? i try <p style="color:red">  {{ form_errors(form.path) }}</p> but don't work

Comment: @FrancescoArreghini logic should be loosely coupled with representation so, if you want a red message, you can do it directly with a [form theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes)

Comment: You might want to see flash messages from symfony. https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages. This service makes it easy to catch all errors and displays them in twig.